# What is the temperature at which Napalm burns?

Tags: temperature, chemical-compounds

I was sitting during a lecture last week in one of my classes, and we were talking about chemical warfare and the history behind it.
My teacher had brought up the use of Napalm during Vietnam. After a few minutes of talking about how it was used, she mentioned it burned at around 4 million degrees Fahrenheit. This seemed to be inaccurate to me, and all I've been able to find online is that it burns between 1,200 to 5,000 degrees Fahrenheit. Which of the two is accurate? Or is neither?

Comment: 4 million is absolutely wrong, that is for sure...

Comment: @JonCuster Burning napalm, core of the sun; basically the same thing right?

Comment: @JMac sure would make fusion machines easier!

Comment: Napalm is no doubt a hydrocarbon.  Look up the flame temperature of gasoline in atmospheric air, and you will be in the right ball park.

Comment: The temperature of the order of millions is not even found on the surface of stars. Only the cores of stars can reach to that order of temperature through a nuclear reaction. The argument of your teacher is quite naive.

Comment: @Jitendra  I'm an 18 year old highschool student. I knew from the get go that 4 million degrees wasn't even accurate. After a quick google search I got that ballpark number, and I raised my hand. She called on me and made my case that her claim was in fact false. She then just ignored what I said and told me I was wrong. Haha, it's always great when your education system has a teacher with PHD in History that is trying to give a brief explanation of some science related thing. I sure am glad my generation is being brainwashed.

Comment: @JMac that's exactly what I said to her and she goes "Well I'm going off of what I've read, and what I've read is true." She must have read something written by a 3 year old.

Answer (score 2):

Your online research is correct.
Napalm relies on oxygen in the atmosphere in order to burn, so it produces just an ordinary flame.

Ordinary flames reach equilibrium at less than few thousand degrees as radiation and convection carry away the limited energy output available from oxygen travelling towards the fuel.

A traditional flame is an "oxidation" process which releases energy by replacing oxygen double bonds with lower energy bonds.  When the fuel is a hydrocarbon, as it is with napalm, oxygen is available only from the atmosphere.  While the fuel is concentrated in a solid/liquid state, the gaseous oxygen in the atmosphere takes it time to get to the napalm.  This is a major factor limiting the temperature of flames.

Comment: *When the fuel is a hydrocarbon, as it is with napalm, the bonding energies of the hydrogen and carbon atoms are about the same as before combustion.* Huh? When a hydrocarbon burns, $C-H$ bonds are broken and $C-O$ bonds and $H_2O$ are formed. The overall process is strongly exothermic.

Comment: @Gert that is true.  But look up the strength of O-H, C-H, O=O bonds

Comment: Consider $CH_4$ + 2$O_2$ yielding $CO_2$ + 2$H_2O$

Comment: All the energy comes from breaking the oxygen double bond.  The C's and H's are just as "happy" to face each other as to face an oxygen.

Comment: The 'strength' is irrelevant here. What matters are the bonding energies. From these the specific combustion energy of Napalm can even be estimated fairly accurately. The released energy has bearing, along with many other factors, on the temperature at which it burns.

Comment: @Gert - I agree.  I am only making the point that the energy available to the flame is gated by the flow of oxygen.  Napalm is not a material which contains its own oxidizer.

Comment: Sorry but I think that last paragraph is ambiguously worded: it reads as if the reaction isn't exothermic at all. I suggest to edit it.

Comment: I gave it a try, check now

Comment: *Note that the energy comes from the breaking of the oxygen double bond.* Again, very ambiguous. Breaking the $OO$ bond *costs* energy. Despite that, the formation of $CO_2$ and and water make the process very exothermic. You are right that access to oxygen has a strong bearing on combustion speed and thus flame temperature.

Comment: tried yet again ...

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a +1. Thanks.